# Python script need simple modification for printing in file

Tags: python

As I coded before on Perl I have no experience in Python so I will ask for a little help how to modify my file.

I have a script that gets a text from URLs and saves multiple htmls. How to modify the script to write the content in one big HTML rather to many separates html files?

I have:

```
for a in article.findAll('a'):
    a.unwrap()

with open(news_folder + '/' + news_file, "w") as f:
    print("<!DOCTYPE html>", file=f)
    print("<html lang='ja'>", file=f)
    print("<head><meta charset='utf-8'></head>", file=f)
    print("<style>p { font-size: 120%; line-height: 3.2; padding-bottom: 20px; }</style>", file=f)
    print("<body>", file=f)
    print(title, file=f)
    print(article, file=f)
    print("</body>", file=f)
    print("</html>", file=f)
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't `print()`, `write()` to the file. And if you plan on doing that several times with different data, but to the same file, then open the file in `append` mode:

```
with open(news_folder + '/single_output.html', "a") as f:
    f.write("<!DOCTYPE html>")
    f.write("<html lang='ja'>")
    #etc.
```

Comment: I would also suggest `os.path.join()`.